# Percentage of total variation explained in a VAR model

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, variance, vector-autoregression, finance

I was studying Campbell, Chen, Viceira (2003)

https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/3163263/campbellnber_assetallocation.pdf?sequence=2

I cannot really understand how they decompose the variance of their model.

As far I know, they simply ran a VAR model, from which they extrapolate a rule to construct an asset allocation rule between stock and bonds.

After doing this they decompose the variance of the asset allocation rule. And then they are able to explain what is the contribution of each variable to the variance of the asset allocation in bonds and in stocks.

I am struggling to understand this. They quickly explain it at pages 25-26 and then in table 4, but the rule is written down.

How to decompose a variance of a multivariate autoregressive process?

Comment: Well Richard, if you took the liberty of checking the link I posted you would see that Campbell and Viceira (NOT ME) called this problem as Percentage of Total Variation in their paper. So please take the liberty of putting it back.

Comment: OK, undone, despite the argument that your title and body do not quite match. Moreover, it looks like Campbell et al. quite liberally use the term "variation" in place of "variance"; for example, in Table 4 "variation" actually means "variance". I perceive such use as unnecessarily confusing.